# Simplify the complex expression to complex numbers (2i)^i

Tags: complex-numbers

I am getting stuck with this one.... This is how far I got 
$$2i = 2 \exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi\right)$$
 $$(2i)^I = 2^{\frac{i}{2}}$$

I'm having trouble moving past that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Notice that:

$$i^2=-1$$
$$i^3=-i$$
$$i^4=1$$
$$i^5=i$$

---

So:

$$(2i)^i=2^ii^i=2^ie^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\exp\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)e^{i\ln(2)}$$